# Local debugging codeigniter with dbg-wizard.php

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, debugging, phped

I removed index.php using this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /job
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|table-images|robots\.txt|css|fonts|js|uploads)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now Cannot debug with PhpEd. PhpEd need to acces dbg-wizard.php file in the root folder but it's not accessible anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /job/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|table-images|robots\.txt|css|fonts|js|uploads|dbg-wizard\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Have added `dbg-wizard.php` to the list of things to skip.